# Custom draw of DatagridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell, custom-draw

I'm using a `DataGridView` with a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and I need to add icons to the left of combobox items. I'm currently using `EditingControlShowing` event along with `ComboBox.DrawItem` event, like this:

```
private void pFiles_dgvFiles_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is ComboBox)
    {
    ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)e.Control;                                
    cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    cb.DrawItem -= combobox1_DrawItem;
    cb.DrawItem += combobox1_DrawItem;
     }
}

private void combobox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Drawing icon here        
}
```

The problem is icons are only drawn as long as the cell is in edit mode. As soon as I click somewhere outside the cell the `CellEndEdit` event is fired and the cell gets repainted (without the icon).

I tried using the `DataGridView.CellPainting` event to resolve this issue, but it causes the dropdown button of the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to disappear.

Any ideas on how to draw an icon after the user finished editing the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you CellPainting event, you can try painting over the existing controls:

```
e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
e.PaintContents(e.ClipBounds);

//Draw your stuff

e.Handled = true;
```

or look into `ComboBoxRenderer` class for the `DrawDropDownButton` method (or `ControlPaint.DrawComboButton` for non-visual styles).

Comment: yes, as for now I'm using this event in way described in this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hta8z9sz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). I was using `ComboBoxRenderer`, but thanks for `ControlPaint`, that suits me better. However, I still haven't figured out how to draw this button in the same flat style as `ComboBoxColumn` does it. The `ButtonState.Flat` differs a bit.