# Exception when adding a new row to my DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, exception, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have this issue. It starts like this:

[image: Begin]

I can double-click the drop arrow and pick a colour OK:

[image: Pick colour]

At this point, I can click the dropdown again and it is correctly selected:

[image: Selected]

The issue is when I want to add a new row. Even if I just go to click on the new row cell:

[image: Click new row]

I then data an data error exception:

[image: Exception]

Thereafter the previous cell draws incorrectly:

[image]

I can't quite work out how to resolve this.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Teigha.Core;
using Teigha.TD;

namespace Viewer
{
    public partial class Editor : Form
    {
        uint[] _CurPalette = Teigha.Core.AllPalettes.getDarkPalette();

        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cboColumn.Name = "Color";

            List<ushort> listColors = new List<ushort>();
            listColors.Add(1);
            listColors.Add(2);
            listColors.Add(3);
            listColors.Add(4);
            listColors.Add(5);
            listColors.Add(6);
            listColors.Add(7);
            listColors.Add(8);
            listColors.Add(9);
            listColors.Add(250);
            listColors.Add(251);
            listColors.Add(252);
            listColors.Add(253);
            listColors.Add(254);
            listColors.Add(255);

            foreach (ushort iColorIndex in listColors)
            {
                using (OdCmColor oColor = new OdCmColor())
                {
                    oColor.setColorIndex(iColorIndex);
                    ComboboxColorItem oColorItem = new ComboboxColorItem(
                        oColor.colorNameForDisplay(),
                        iColorIndex,
                        Color.FromArgb(oColor.red(), oColor.green(), oColor.blue()));
                    cboColumn.Items.Add(oColorItem);
                }
            }

            this.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cboColumn);
        }

        private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox theCB = (ComboBox)e.Control;
                theCB.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
                try
                {
                    theCB.DrawItem -= new DrawItemEventHandler(this.combobox1_DrawItem);
                }
                catch { }
                theCB.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(this.combobox1_DrawItem);
            }
        }

        private void combobox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Color c = Color.Empty;
            string s = "";
            Brush br = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
            Brush brBack;
            Rectangle rDraw;
            bool bSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(e.State & DrawItemState.Selected);
            bool bValue = Convert.ToBoolean(e.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit);

            rDraw = e.Bounds;
            rDraw.Inflate(-1, -1);

            if (bSelected & !bValue)
            {
                brBack = Brushes.LightBlue;
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, rDraw);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rDraw);
            }
            else
            {
                brBack = Brushes.White;
                g.FillRectangle(brBack, e.Bounds);
            }

            try
            {
                //s = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
                ComboboxColorItem oColorItem = (ComboboxColorItem)((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index];
                s = oColorItem.ToString();
                c = oColorItem.Value;
            }
            catch
            {
                s = "red";
                c = Color.Red;
            }

            SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(c);
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 5, e.Bounds.Top + 3, 10, 10);
            g.FillRectangle(b, r);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r);
            g.DrawString(s, Form.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 25, e.Bounds.Top + 1);

            b.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
        }

        private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class ComboboxColorItem
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public ushort Index { get; }
        public Color Value { get; }

        public ComboboxColorItem(string Name, ushort Index, Color Value)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Index = Index;
            this.Value = Value;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

If I put this code into the form load event:

```
this.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(new ComboboxColorItem("red", 1, Color.Red));
```

Then I immediately get the exception.

I tried adding a secondary default constructor and it made no difference:

```
public class ComboboxColorItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ushort Index { get; set; }
    public Color Value { get; set; }

    public ComboboxColorItem()
    {
        this.Name = "red";
        this.Index = 1;
        this.Value = Color.Red;
    }
    public ComboboxColorItem(string Name, ushort Index, Color Value)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Index = Index;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

I also tried adding this to the load event:

```
cboColumn.ValueType = typeof(ComboboxColorItem);
```

Didn't make a difference.

Update:

I have used the CellParsing answer and I seem to no longer gave crashes:

[image: CellParsing results]

My only comment now is that I was hoping that the block of colour would remain visible in the cell. But I only see the block of colour when I click the drop arrow. Is this a separate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView` has trouble with parsing the selected color item. I suggest that you apply custom parsing logic to that column:

```
DataGridView1.CellParsing += ColorCellParsing;

private void ColorCellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    var column = grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
    if (column == null || column.Name != "Color")
        return;
    foreach (ComboboxColorItem item in column.Items)
    {
        if (item.Name == (string) e.Value)
        {
            e.Value = item;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
            break;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This also does not seem to work. I thought it helped at first.

Comment: I notice that in your example and in my debugging we are just looking at the text value. But we also have the actual Color object. How do we parse that?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, color name is that `e.Value` returns (due to ToString() implementation). but it is possible to change ValueMember  of column `cboColumn.ValueMember = "Index";`

Comment: It is ok now.  I updated the question but I think I should accept this and do new one.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482534/custom-draw-of-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get something other than strings, set the `ValueType` of the column to `typeof(<data type>)`
for example if it is int

```
this.gridViewSettings.Columns("columnName").ValueType= typeof(Int32);
```

or

```
this.ComboboxCellcolumnName.ValueType = typeof(int);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried hitting the star and get the same error.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried both `cboColumn.ValueType = typeof(Color);` and `cboColumn.ValueType = typeof(ComboboxColorItem);` and it seems to make no difference. :(